# Replace text failing

Tags: powershell

Been trying various combinations but I just cannot replace the text I want below - I keep on getting an error. I have a feeling it does not like the "\" or even the "$" I have added but cannot see what is wrong - any help would be appreciated. All I want to do is to replace some text to something else.

```
PS C:\> $f = "C:\LocalGAR\WIN\Comp\register\x86_v1.0"

PS C:\> $f -replace ('C:\LocalGAR','\\comp.gci.tk.com\files$')
The regular expression pattern C:\LocalGAR is not valid.
At line:1 char:1
+ $f -replace ('C:\LocalGAR','\\comp.gci.tk.com\files$')
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (C:\LocalGAR:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidRegularExpression
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the slashes in your search pattern

manually escaped

```
$f -replace ('C:\\LocalGAR','\\comp.gci.tk.com\files$')
```

or the safer automatic escaped string

```
$f -replace ([Regex]::Escape('C:\LocalGAR'),'\\comp.gci.tk.com\files$')
```

returns

```
\\comp.gci.tk.com\files$\WIN\Comp\register\x86_v1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried calling 'replace' as a method like so:

```
$f.replace('C:\LocalGAR','\\comp.gci.tk.com\files$')
```

This doesn't throw an error for me where your line does.
EDIT (from Mathias R. Jessen): 
Yes it is also good to note that `"-replace"` is completely different to `".replace"`

Comment: Just to be clear - `.Replace()` and `-replace` is *not* the same

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell's `-replace` operator uses regular expressions for pattern matching, and they use backslash `\` to identify regular expression groups - e.g. `\s` is "any whitespace character (spaces, tabs)".

It's trying to match `\L` to a [regular expression command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx), and can't find it, and is throwing an error.

The replace text for `-replace` is a normal string, not a regex, so the `$` is fine in there.

(The two options, as given by the other answers, are to use the `$string.replace()` method which does literal string replacement, or to escape the special characters in the regex so they are not commands - either by hand or with `[regex]::escape()`).